# How to pick the image from gallery, crop the image and the save image as profile image in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

hello please help me in this regard I want to select pic from gallery and crop the pic and save the pic in some folder

Please help me in this regard

```
enter code here
```

private void ProfilePic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent = new Intent();

```
        Intent.SetType("image/*");
        Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "EZ-Gift Profile Pic"), PickImageId);
    }


    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
            //Toast.MakeText(this, path, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Toast.MakeText(this, uri.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();

            ProfilePic.SetImageURI(uri);

            string path = GetPathToImage(data.Data);

            edit = prefs.Edit();
            edit.PutString("ProfilePicUri", uri.ToString());
            Toast.MakeText(this, uri.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Toast.MakeText(this, path, ToastLength.Long).Show();


        }
    }
    private string GetPathToImage(Android.Net.Uri contentURI)
    {
        ICursor cursor = ContentResolver.Query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.MoveToFirst();
        string documentId = cursor.GetString(0);
        documentId = documentId.Split(':')[1];
        cursor.Close();

        cursor = ContentResolver.Query(
        Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri,
        null, MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " = ? ", new[] { documentId }, null);
        cursor.MoveToFirst();
        string path = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data));
        cursor.Close();

        return path;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to Crop the image.Modify your OnActivityResult code , try like this. Hope this may help you.

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
            {
                Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
                //Toast.MakeText(this, path, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                Toast.MakeText(this, uri.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();

                // It will crop the image accordingly.  
                cropPicture(uri);

                string path = GetPathToImage(data.Data);

                Toast.MakeText(this, uri.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                Toast.MakeText(this, path, ToastLength.Long).Show();


            }
            else if(requestCode == CROP_PIC)
            {
                // Get your cropped image here using Bundle and save the bitmap in particular location.
            }
        }

 private void cropPicture(Android.Net.Uri picUri)
        {
            try
            {
                // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
                // support it)
                Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                // indicate image type and Uri
                cropIntent.SetDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
                // set crop properties
                cropIntent.PutExtra("crop", "true");
                // indicate aspect of desired crop
                cropIntent.PutExtra("aspectX", 2);
                cropIntent.PutExtra("aspectY", 1);
                // indicate output X and Y
                cropIntent.PutExtra("outputX", 256);
                cropIntent.PutExtra("outputY", 256);
                // retrieve data on return
                cropIntent.PutExtra("return-data", true);
                // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
                StartActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC);
            }
            // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe)
            {
                Toast toast = Toast
                        .MakeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!", ToastLength.Long);
                toast.Show();
            }
        }
```